# Split string by delimiter strtok weird behaviour

Tags: c++, string, parsing, arduino

I am trying to split string ,but unfortunately `strtok` behaves weirdly

I have following string `get|user=password|23|info|hello` I have tried widely used method using strtok, but unfortunately it treats `=` as delimiter and I cannot parse my string. 
So `get` parsed correctly than parsed only `user`, but not `user=password`.

Please help to find the problem or suggest any other way to split the string.
I am programming for Arduino.

Thanks

Code

```
  const char delimeter = '|';
  char *token;
  token = strtok(requestString, &delimeter);
  // Handle parsed  
  token = strtok(NULL, &delimeter);
```

Comment: Try using a string literal for the delimiter rather than an individual, undelimited `char`. I'd also recommend avoiding `strtok()` but that's independent from your question.

Comment: Important note: requestString will be mangled by strtok because strtok will replace delim characters with nulls wherever it finds them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok),

> delim -   pointer to the null-terminated byte string identifying delimiters

The requirement that your approach doesn't fit is *null terminated*. You take the address of a single `char`, but clearly you cannot access anything past this one symbol. `strtok`, however, searches for `\0` character which terminates the string. Thus you're entering undefined behaviour land.

Instead, use

```
const char* delimiter = "|";
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have problem with parsing number (integer) in my case 23, token is empty (null) when I try to parse next toke. Maybe you know what can cause such problem

Comment: @fwouxicd perfect opportunity to make another question.  This question is short and to the point. It would only be damaged by bolting more stuff on.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
  const char delimeter = '|';
```

to this:

```
  const char * delimeter = "|";  // note the double quotes
```